# How do we prove the set of functions from the naturals to the set of perfect squares is countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $F$ be the set of all functions defined from the naturals to the set $P$ of perfect squares: $F=\{f:\Bbb{N}\to P\}$.

Set $F$ includes, for example, $f(n) = n^2$, $f(n) = 36$ , $f(n) = 100$, $f(n) = (2n)^2$ and so on. (It is an infinite set.)

How do we prove it is countable?

Comment: If I have a set $S$, do you know how to prove it's countable? (*Hint:* You have to exhibit a bijection between $S$ and another set, which one? Can you find such a bijection for your set?)

Comment: F, I apologize I could have worded it better.

Answer (score 2):

You don't, because it isn't.  Since $P$ is countable, $F$ has the same cardinality as the set of functions $f: \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$, which has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$.